# Trying to update my AWS DynamoDB call from v2 to v3 in js but it's giving errors

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

`

```
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb"; // ES6 import
   const { DynamoDBClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb"); // CommonJS import
      import { DynamoDBDocumentClient, PutCommand } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

    const docClinet = new DynamoDBClient({});

   const AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    {
      DynamoDB
    } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");

    let awsConfig = {
    "region": "us-west-2",
    "endpoint": "http://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    "accessKeyId": "*insert keyID*",
    "secretAccessKey": "*insert secret key*"
      };
      AWS.config.update(awsConfig);

    let fetchOneByKey = function () {
      var params = {
      TableName: 'scout',
       Key: {
      "2637": { N: "4" }
       },
       ProjectionExpression: 'auto_docked'
      };
      docClinet.get(params, function (err, data) {
       if (err) {
          console.log("users::fetchOneByKey :: error -" + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       }
       else {
         console.log("users::fetchOneByKey :: error -" + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
       }
     });

      }`
```

^^ Here is the code that I wrote to try and call from AWS DynamoDB tables. At first, it was quite simple to do after following some videos, but it then started giving errors to update from v2 to v3. There's no youtube video to follow up with because it's such a new update, so I followed up with the documentation provided by AWS. However, it's too confusing and vague to me for someone who has barely worked with AWS. With the best of my abilities, I attempted to write an updated version. And, it gives me errors like: "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module". Any ideas as to how to fix it?

I hope that the terminal will give me no errors when I type in: node Read.js. Additionally, I expect to call something within the table by giving a specific location.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) declaration in a source file, the source file must be interpreted by the JavaScript runtime as a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). For Node.js, that means you need to add the following to package.json:

```
 "type" : "module"
```

Alternatively, you can rename your source file from `app.js` to `app.mjs`. But don't use both import and require.

In you prefer, you can use CommonJS `require` instead of ES6 `import`. For example:

```
const { DynamoDBClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");

const { DynamoDBDocumentClient, PutCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb");

// Note that translateConfig is optional in the DynamoDBDocumentClient.from() call below
const translateConfig = { marshallOptions, unmarshallOptions };

const ddbClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "us-east-1" });
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(ddbClient, translateConfig);
```

And then use the low-level `ddbClient` or high-level, document-based `docClient` as needed to send commands. For example:

```
try {
  const params = {
    TableName: "mytable",
    Item: {
      id: 1,
      name: "james",
    },
  };
  const rsp = await docClient.send(new PutCommand(params));
  console.log("Successful put:", rsp);
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Error:", err);
}
```